# Convert date to specific format as Month Date, year

Tags: r, date

Is there way to convert the below code into Mar 10, 2020?

```
weekdays.Date(as.Date("2020-03-10", format="%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work:

```
 format(as.Date("2020-03-10"), "%b %d, %Y")
 # "Mar 10, 2020"
```